# Start an Intent from a On ClickListener

Tags: android

I want to click Start button with sound and go to next activity with intent. The code below doesn't work. The button has sound but cannot go to next activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 5);
    music = sp.load(this, R.raw.munchausen, 1);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sp.play(music, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    });
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 5);
    music = sp.load(this, R.raw.munchausen, 1);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sp.play(music, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Please change your code to this.

Comment: Thank you so much!!